# Multiplicative lattice with $(a \land b)\ast(a\lor b)=a \ast b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, divisibility, order-theory, gcd-and-lcm, lattice-orders

The natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ carry two (order-theoretic) lattice structures: One, say $L_1$, is the division lattice (where the join is the least common multiple and the meet is the greatest common divisor). Another, say $L_2$, is the one induced from the total order on $\mathbb{N}$ (i.e. join=maximum and meet=minimum).

The natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ are not simply a set but they come with two monoid structures: addition and multiplication.
The lattice $L_2$ becomes a [residuated lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residuated_lattice) with addition, while $L_1$ does not become one with multiplication. Nevertheless, in both $L_1$ and $L_2$ we have the following identity

$$(a \land b)\ast(a\lor b)=a \ast b$$ where the symbol $\ast$ denotes multiplication in the case of $L_1$ and addition in the case of $L_2$.

Do lattices (which are additionally monoids) satisfying the above property have a name? What are other lattices (appearing in nature) with that property? Is my observation at all interesting or not particularly fruitful?

Comment: Lattices that are also monoids (and whose join and meet distributive over the monoid multiplication) are sometimes called *lattice-ordered monoids*. See for instance [this paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/MB/132.4/mb132_4_3.pdf), [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20016588) or [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45943/lattice-ordered-commutative-monoids). I think the term is also used in Birkhoff's *Lattice Theory* even though I would have to check to be sure.

Comment: I stand corrected. Birkhoff calls a lattice with a binary multiplication that distributes over join and meet a *multiplicative lattice* or *$m$-lattice*.

Comment: The notion of a [quantale](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantale) seems also relevant.

Comment: The lattice of (ring-theoretic) ideals of the integers (ordered by inclusion and with multiplication the usual multiplication of ideals) is an example of a multiplicative lattice with the above property. This is because it is anti-isomorphic (as a multiplicative lattice) to the division lattice of the natural numbers starting at zero (with the usual multiplication of natural numbers as multiplication). An anti-isomorphism is given by the map $n\mapsto n\mathbb{Z}$.